# Indexed unions and definitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I've been trying to understand how to explicitly state an indexed union/intersection of sets. Here is an example:

> $X$ $=$ $\bigcup S_\alpha$ where $\alpha \in I$

First of all, how would one read this? Would it be the union of all sets $S$ that like $S_a$, $S_b$, $S_c$ etc where $a,b,c \in I$ ?

So, if I were to explicitly state $X$ would be $X$ $=$ {$x \in S_\alpha :$ (not sure what goes here)}

And what about the intersection?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! The notation $$X=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} S_\alpha$$ defines $$X=\{x:\exists \alpha\in I:x\in S_\alpha\}$$

Similarly, $$X=\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} S_\alpha = \{x:\forall\alpha\in I:x\in S_\alpha\}$$

Answer (score 8):

Suppose $I$ is a set and you have a collection $\{ S_{\alpha}\, :\, \alpha \in I \}$ of sets indexed by $I$. For example, if $I=\{1,2,3\}$ then your collection of sets would be $\{ S_1, S_2, S_3 \}$. Then we define the union of all the $S_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in I$ by:
$$\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} S_{\alpha} = \{ x\, :\, x \in S_{\alpha}\ \text{for some}\ \alpha \in I \}$$
It's the set of all those things that appear in at least one of the $S_{\alpha}$s. So for example if $I=\{1,2,3\}$ then
$$\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} S_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\alpha=1}^3 S_{\alpha} = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3$$

The intersection is similar:
$$\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} S_{\alpha}= \{ x\, :\, x \in S_{\alpha}\ \text{for all}\ \alpha \in I \}$$

---

As for how you read it, that's up to you really, as long as it's clear. Common ways include:

- *the union over all $\alpha$ in $I$ of $S_{\alpha}$*
- *the union of all the $S_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha$ in $I$*
- *the union of all the $S_{\alpha}$s* $\qquad \leftarrow$ if $I$ is clear from context