# What do we mean by $\bigcup_{i\in I}^{} T_i$ where $T_i$ are sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

What do we mean by $\bigcup_{i\in I}^{} T_i$ where $T_i$ are sets?

Actually my question is more about what do we mean by index set $I$? Is it like sequence? To see more clear it wouldn't hurt to take $I$ as $\mathbb N$ so $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb N}^{} T_i$ would be $ T_1 \cup T_2 \cup T_3 \dots$

However I couldn't imagine other cases different from $\mathbb N$. Could you help me to figure out this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indexed unions and definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358531/indexed-unions-and-definitions)

Comment: $x$ will be an element of the set if and only if some $i\in I$ exists such that $x\in T_i$. That is a complete characterisation of the set.

Comment: so we have as many sets  $T_i$as set $I$, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't always take $I$ as $\mathbb{N}$, since $I$ could be uncountable, for example $I = \mathbb{R}$.  If $I$ is countably infinite, you could take $I = \mathbb{N}$, but it might not be the most natural choice in the context. That's why there is a general $I$.

Comment: A delicate question seems to define a "family of sets $T_i$" when $I$ is a general set. I understand it when all the $T_i$ are subsets of another set $E$, so the family is just a function $I\rightarrow {\cal P}(E)$. Is there another definition? I tried to look in Bourbaki but it is not clearly explained.

Answer (score 0):

$I$ is the index set, which is defined as 
$I:=\{i | T_i$ exists$ \}$
$I$ can be any set, it can be equal to $\mathbb N$ , $\mathbb R$ or $[0 ,1]$ etc.

**Edit** : I corrected the definition.

Comment: According to your answer $I$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In analysis and topology you often want to associate sets with real numbers. For example, when considering some open neighborhood around $x$ - $U_x$. Then you often want to study some sort of union or intersection of the neighbourhoods, when $x \in A$ and $A$ may be uncountable.